# Simplifying Try, Except for yahooquery

Tags: python, yahoo-finance, simplify, try-except

I am trying to get about 10 stock attributes from yahooquery. When some data is not available (e.g. when the company is not making a profit, there is no PE ratio) it raises KeyError. I want to return zero in that case. Is there any way how to simplify my code and not to put Try/Except to every attribute?

````
def data(ticker): #pulling data about stock from Yahoo Finance API
    try:
        company_name = Ticker(ticker).quote_type[ticker]["shortName"]
    except KeyError:
        company_name = 0
    try:
        stock_price = Ticker(ticker).financial_data[ticker]["currentPrice"]
    except KeyError:
        stock_price = 0
    try:
        change = Ticker(ticker).history(interval='1mo', start=(datetime.datetime.today() - datetime.timedelta(days=90)), end=datetime.datetime.today())
        change = change["open"]
        growth_or_loose = ((change.iloc[-1] / change.iloc[0]) - 1)
    except:
        growth_or_loose = 0
    try:
        recommendation = Ticker(ticker).financial_data[ticker]["recommendationKey"]
    except KeyError:
        recommendation = 0
    try:
        market_cap = Ticker(ticker).summary_detail[ticker]["marketCap"]
    except KeyError:
        market_cap = 0
    try:
        pe = Ticker(ticker).summary_detail[ticker]["trailingPE"]
    except KeyError:
        pe = 0
    try:
        pb = Ticker(ticker).key_stats[ticker]["priceToBook"]
    except KeyError:
        pb = 0
    try:
        rev_growth = Ticker(ticker).financial_data[ticker]["revenueGrowth"]
    except KeyError:
        rev_growth = 0
    try:
        ern_growth = Ticker(ticker).financial_data[ticker]["earningsGrowth"]
    except KeyError:
        ern_growth = 0
    profit_margin = Ticker(ticker).financial_data[ticker]["profitMargins"]
    try:
        debt2equity = Ticker(ticker).financial_data[ticker]["debtToEquity"]
    except KeyError:
        debt2equity = 0
    data =  company_name, stock_price, growth_or_loose,  recommendation, market_cap, pe, pb, rev_growth, ern_growth, profit_margin, debt2equity
    return list(data)```
````

Comment: Did you find any of the answers helpful? Please upvote helpful answers and accept the one you find most helpful in your case. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In this case you could use the dictionary's get-method instead which would return None instead of KeyError in case the dictionary doesn't contain that key, or if default value (2nd arg) is supplied it would return the default value.

```py
my_dict = {
    "hello" : "world"
}

try:
    hello = my_dict["NONEXISTING"]
except KeyError:
    hello = "greetings"

# the try/except block can be replaced with this, and since the key
# doesn't exist, the method returns "greetings" instead of raising a KeyError
hello = my_dict.get("NONEXISTING", "greetings")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use defaultdict from collections to give a default value to any variable that does not have a value.
First of all convert your dictionary to defaultdict

```
# Python program to demonstrate 
# defaultdict 
  
  
from collections import defaultdict 
  
  
# Function to return a default 
# values for keys that is not 
# present 
def def_value(): 
    return "Not Present"
      
# Defining the dict 
d = defaultdict(def_value) 
d["a"] = 1
d["b"] = 2
  
print(d["a"]) 
print(d["b"]) 
print(d["c"])
```

Output:

```
1
2
Not Present
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from yahooquery import Ticker
import time
symbols = {
    'AAPL': 'B12','BABA': 'B13','MSFT': 'B14',
}
tickers = Ticker(list(symbols.keys()), asynchronous=True)

try:
    while True:
        prices = tickers.price
        for k, v in symbols.items():
            try:
                a = str(prices[k]['regularMarketPrice'])
                print ("currentPrice : "+a)
            except Exception as e:print(0)
            try:
                b = str(prices[k]['marketCap'])
                print ("marketCap : "+b)
            except Exception as e:print(0)
            try:
                c = str(prices[k]['payoutRation'])
                print ("payoutRation : "+c)
            except Exception as e:print(0)
            except Exception as e:
                print(e)
    time.sleep(2)
except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

Also you can export this data to excel with:

```
import xlwings as xw
wb = xw.Book('Filename.xlsx')
sht1 = wb.sheets['Sheet1']
for k, v in symbols.items():
    try:
        sht1.range(v).value = str(prices[k]['regularMarketPrice'])
        v1=v.replace("B", "C")
        sht1.range(v1).value = str(prices[k]['regularMarketDayHigh'])
        v2=v1.replace("C", "D")
        sht1.range(v2).value = str(prices[k]['regularMarketDayLow'])
    except Exception as e:
            print(e)
```